# $L^p$ estimates for $\bar\partial$ operator on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

When $p=2$ we have the following Hörmander's theorem.

> **Thm :** Let $X$ be a connected open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $a >0$.
>   If $f \in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(X)$ and  $$\int_X |f(z)|^2
> (1+|z|^2)^{2-a} d\lambda(z) < \infty, $$ then the
>   Cauchy-Riemann equation $\bar\partial u = f$ has a solution $u \in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(X)$ such that  $$ a \int_X |u(z)|^2 
> (1+|z|^2)^{-a} d\lambda(z) \leq \int_X |f(z)|^2
> (1+|z|^2)^{2-a} d\lambda(z).$$

When $1<p<\infty$, I found the same type of estimates but in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and with more assumptions on $X$ (like "$X$ is a strongly pseudo-convex domain with regular boundary").

My question is : can I have the same estimates in $\mathbb{C}$ for general open connected sets $X$ when $1<p<\infty$?